# ¿Cómo detengo todos los threads excepto uno?

Tags: python, hilos

Tengo un código de **Python** que funciona con hilos, si doy por ejemplo `10 hilos`, hay un momento del código que tengo que ejecutar una acción solo con ***un hilo*** y no con los 10

```
class Main():
    def preparar(self, accion, threads):
        self.accion = accion
        self.threads = threads
        for x in range(threads):
            threading.Thread(target=Main.comprobar, args=(self, self.accion)).start()
    def ejecutar(self, accion):
        res = ejemplo.click()
        if 'ok' in res.text:
            print("Ejecutada con exito")
            os._exit(0)
        else:
            print("Fallo al ejecutar")
            os._exit(0)

    def comprobar(self, accion):
        a = ejemplo.ver().text
        if 'correcto' in a:
            self.ejecutar(self.accion)
        else:
            print("Volviendo a comprobar...")
            time.sleep(0.04)
            self.comprobar(self.accion)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    ejemplo = Ejemplo("usuario","***********")
    ejemplo.login()
    accion = input("Accion ")
    threads = int(input("Hilos: "))

    w = Main()
    w.preparar(accion, threads)
```

En este código en el valor threads uso **10**, y a la hora que `comprobar()`, su respuesta sea ***correcto***, quiero realizar una sola vez `ejecutar()`, no una vez con cada hilo (es decir, 10 veces)

Comment: ¿Con un solo hilo que caiga en el if en comprobar ya se podrian parar el resto y ejecutar una sola vez ejecutar?

Comment: @FJSevilla Sí, los 10 hilos interpretan el **correcto**, pero solo uno tendría que `ejecutar()`

Comment: @FJSevilla También otra forma sería, cuando el primer hilo interprete el **correcto**, se terminen todos los hilos excepto uno y así ese hilo que capturo el _"correcto"_ haga `ejecutar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un simple candado de forma que el primer hilo que se tope con "correcto" y pueda adquirir el candado se encargue de llamar a `ejecutar`. El resto, en el momento que se encuentren con el candado adquirido pueden simplemente detenerse:

```
class Main:
    def preparar(self, accion, threads):
        self.accion = accion
        self.threads = threads
        self._comp_lock = threading.Lock()

        for x in range(threads):
            threading.Thread(target=self.comprobar).start()

    def ejecutar(self):
        res = ejemplo.click()
        if 'ok' in res:
            print("Ejecutada con éxito")
            os._exit(0)
        else:
            print("Fallo al ejecutar")
            os._exit(1)

    def comprobar(self):
        while not self._comp_lock.locked():
            a = ejemplo.ver().text
            if 'correcto' in a:
                if self._comp_lock.acquire(blocking=False):
                    self.ejecutar()
                break
            print("Volviendo a comprobar...")
            time.sleep(0.04)
```

Es recomendable que evites la recursión en lo posible, es menos eficiente, considerada menos pitónica y encima está limitada de forma conservativa a 1000 llamadas por defecto para evitar desbordamientos de pila.

Comment: Lo pruebo y te comento, pinta muy bien

Comment: Vale, tras comprobar tu respuesta, es justo lo que necesitaba, detener los threads sobrantes y dejar que uno solo ejecute una acción